# DataTable sort column based on element's attribute

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am trying to sort a DataTable column based on a custom attribute that the column has. My table look like this:

```
<table class="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="15%" scope="col" class="currency-field">${msg_amountLabel}</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-raw="${order.totalPrice}" class="order-history-list-price">${order.formattedPrice}</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And my JS looks like this:

```
        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["currency-desc"] = function (a, b) {

            return 1;
        };
        jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort["currency-asc"] = function (a, b) {

            return 0;
        }

        tableObject.DataTable({
            "info": false,
            "paging": false,
            "order": orderObject,
            "columnDefs": [{
                    "targets"  : 'currency-field',
                    "type": "currency",
                    "data": "data-raw"
                }]
        });
```

For now I have dummy values in my sorters to test if they are being called, I was expecting to receive the element in the sorters but I receive only the value.

Is it possible to pass some parameter to the columnnDefs to infor that I want the value from the attribute data-raw? Or any other way to inform the dataTable sort to use the data-raw instead of the field value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using `data-raw` you can use `data-sort` for configuration-by-convention; datatables will automatically pick this up and use it for the sort value with no need for any additional code on your part.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dataTable').dataTable();
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table class="dataTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style='text-align:left'>Sort Col</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td data-sort="1">First</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-sort="4">Fourth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-sort="3">Third</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td data-sort="2">Second</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Additional info: https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html